# Working with a QMenu and passing of arguments

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu, qt-signals

I have a `QMenu`which has several menu items built dynamically.

To this end, I iterate over a collection of menu items, containing the name and Action ( which would need to be taken if the menu item were hit), and keep adding them to a the context menu. All the menu items need to be connected **to a common slot**.

But somehow the trigger action does not happen. i.e. the connect statement is reached, but the control does not pass into the specified SLOT, no action is taken.

```
for (int i=0; i<Action_List.size();i++)
{
    tempAct1 = Action_List.at(i); //Action List has the list of Actions
    Context_Menu->addAction(tempAct1);
}
if (Context_Menu!=NULL) {
    Context_Menu->exec(QCursor::pos());
    int r = connect(Context_Menu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction *)), 
                    this, SLOT(SPlusCommand(QAction *)));
}

int P14MainWindow::SPlusCommand ( QAction* Action)
{
    QVariant tempstr = Action->data();
    QString Qs = tempstr.toString();
    return QPwLocalClient::ExecuteCommand(Qs);
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with this, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you should move `connect` **before** `exec()`:

```
connect(Context_Menu, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction *)), 
        this, SLOT(SPlusCommand(QAction *)));
Context_Menu->exec(QCursor::pos());
```

Because `exec` executes menu *synchronously*, what means that it will return from this method only when all your interaction with menu is finished — too late to connect something after it.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to connect the individual actions with your slot.

```
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(yourSlot())
```

Comment: Not quite right, because he wants to know from slot which action was invoked. `QMenu::triggered(QAction*)` signal is also legitimate, and as [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qmenu.html#triggered) says, it is made right for that reason: when you connect multiple *similar* actions to same slot.